# Bitmap to base64 encoding is not working. Broken image.Also, error 'Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string' is thrown from server

Tags: android

I'm encoding a bitmap to base64 string to send as JSON body in a POST request in my app. The server is displays an error (in response) "*Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string.*" But When I try to send a base64 encoded string obtained from any online encoding tools such as [this](https://freeonlinetools24.com/base64-image), I'm able to successfully send it to the server. That makes me wonder whenther I'm doing something wrong in the encoding processs. When I try to decode the app encoded base64 string using the online tools, it shows the top part of image and not full. What I'm doing wrong here?

**Code:**

```
public class ScanActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
String resultValue;
String TAG="JJJJ";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan);
    // Retrieve the parameter.
     resultValue = getIntent().getStringExtra("myParam");

    CropImage.activity()
            .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
            .setActivityTitle("My Crop")
            .setCropShape(CropImageView.CropShape.RECTANGLE)
            .setCropMenuCropButtonTitle("Done")
            .setRequestedSize(400, 400)
            .setCropMenuCropButtonIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .start(this);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    // handle result of CropImageActivity
    if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            //((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.quick_start_cropped_image)).setImageURI(result.getUri());
            try {
                final Uri imageUri = result.getUri();
                final InputStream imageStream;
                imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                final Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.quick_start_cropped_image)).setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
                String encodedImage = encodeImage(selectedImage);
                testImage(selectedImage);
                if (resultValue.equals("eid")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.putExtra("EID_MESSAGE", encodedImage);
                    setResult(2, intent);
                    finish();
                }if (resultValue.equals("tl")){
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.putExtra("TL_MESSAGE", encodedImage);
                    setResult(4, intent);
                    finish();
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Toast.makeText(
                    this, "Cropping successful, Sample: " + result.getSampleSize(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Cropping failed: " + result.getError(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
private String encodeImage(Bitmap bm) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
    byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();
    return Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.NO_WRAP);
}

public void testImage(Bitmap originalBitmap){
    //Bitmap originalBitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); //or whatever image you want
    Log.d(TAG, "original bitmap byte count: " + originalBitmap.getByteCount());

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    originalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
    Log.d(TAG, "byte array output stream size: " + baos.size());

    byte[] outputByteArray = baos.toByteArray();
    Log.d(TAG, "output byte array length: " + outputByteArray.length);

    String base64EncodedString = Base64.encodeToString(outputByteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Log.d(TAG, "base64 encoded string length: " + base64EncodedString.length());

    byte[] inputByteArray = Base64.decode(base64EncodedString, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Log.d(TAG, "input byte array length: " + inputByteArray.length);

    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(inputByteArray);
    Log.d(TAG, "byte array input stream size: " + bais.available());

    Bitmap decodedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bais);
    Log.d(TAG, "decoded bitmap byte count: " + decodedBitmap.getByteCount());

    Log.d(TAG, "decoded bitmap same as original bitmap? " + decodedBitmap.sameAs(originalBitmap));
}
}
```

**Stacktrace**

```
2020-06-22 14:36:21.332 16367-16367/com.example.upload I/PPPPPP: 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

2020-06-22 09:36:21.177 16367-16367/com.example.upload D/JJJJ: original bitmap byte count: 478800
2020-06-22 09:36:21.257 16367-16367/com.example.upload D/JJJJ: byte array output stream size: 153955
2020-06-22 09:36:21.257 16367-16367/com.example.upload D/JJJJ: output byte array length: 153955
2020-06-22 09:36:21.259 16367-16367/com.example.upload D/JJJJ: base64 encoded string length: 207977
2020-06-22 09:36:21.268 16367-16367/com.example.upload D/JJJJ: input byte array length: 153955
2020-06-22 09:36:21.268 16367-16367/com.example.upload D/JJJJ: byte array input stream size: 153955
2020-06-22 09:36:21.275 16367-16367/com.example.upload D/JJJJ: decoded bitmap byte count: 478800
2020-06-22 09:36:21.275 16367-16367/com.example.upload D/JJJJ: decoded bitmap same as original bitmap? true
```

**Encoded String From App:**

```
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
```

**Error Response From Server:**

[image]

*When I try to decode the app encoded bas64 string using online tools:*

It shows only the top portion of the image.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

When used with the flag Base64.DEFAULT, Android's Base64 encoder includes a line break character after every 76 characters. Maybe this is not expected by the server? Try using the flag Base64.NO_WRAP, perhaps together with Base64.URL_SAFE. Also, are you sure you are sending the whole string? The example output you are adding is not the whole encoded string, as it is only 4059 characters long.

Comment: I use the android's in built encoder. do you know how to use it in the correct way?